# How to add Youtube Video

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube, embed

I am intending to add a feature in my app to allow users to add youtube videos. Is there any way that I can allow the user to select and embed youtube videos directly on the iPhone itself? Something like imagePickerController but used for youtube videos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write this yourself using the YouTube API (Google has an [Objective-C framework](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) for this) and a table view controller.

If you want to embed it, use a web view.